# JQuery multiple selector with next() sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery

As we know:

```
$('#a').addClass('current');
$('#b').addClass('current');
$('#c').addClass('current');
```

↓

```
$('#a, #b, #c').addClass('current');
```

But, can jQuery get multiple selectors with `next()` sibling?

```
$('#d').next().addClass('current');
$('#e').next().addClass('current');
$('#f').next().addClass('current');
```

actually I mean if we can reference all of these selector (a, b, c, d's next, e's next, f's next) in one line?

Comment: of course you can....

Comment: `$('#d,#e,#f').next().addClass('current');`

Comment: @PranavCBalan sorry, plz see my edit.

Comment: `$('#d,#e,#f').next()`, it's just one line of code???

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: I mean all elements including a,b,c, because they are binding with the same method `addClass(current)`

Comment: @SamSu : `$([$('#a, #b, #c'),$('#d,#e,#f').next()]).addClass('current');`

Comment: @SamSu : or try :`$('#a, #b, #c, #d + * ,#e + *,#f + *').addClass('current');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way you can

```
$('#d,#e,#f').next().addClass('current');
```

---

**UPDATE** :
I think you need to combine both the selector, in that case  you can use **[`add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/)** method to combine them as *@PatrickEvans* said.

```
$('#d,#e,#f').next().add('#a, #b, #c').addClass('current');
```

---

or use [next adjacent sibling selector(`+`)](https://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/) instead of [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method

```
$('#a, #b, #c, #d + * , #e + *, #f + *').addClass('current');
```

---

Comment: thank you~. And could I do the same thing in AngularJS?

Comment: @SamSu : I'm not familiar with angular... even though I think it will

Comment: The array one won't work, as it just makes a jQuery object wrapping the array. It doesn't make a jQuery object representing all the elements matching the selectors. You could use [.add](http://api.jquery.com/add) though: `$("#a,#b,#c").add("#d,#e,#f")` or `.add($("#d").next())`